# just upgraded to 14.04 and my super key doesn't work and I can't find the dash either

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, skype

I have been using an old version of Ubuntu  and then Skype stopped working an I was told I would need to upgrade. So now I have had the experience of upgrading to this new version 14.04 and Skype works again but sadly the super key doesn't work, I have no side bar, I can't find the dash, Google chrome doesn't work and my mouse pad scroll doesn't either (not that the this really matters to me).

Answer (score 1):

As Akiva wrote, a fresh install would probably fix it. However, before doing that, you may want to ensure that all packages which should be installed are installed. You can do so by installing the *ubuntu-desktop* package.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Just adding on to this, you may have to do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu desktop`

Answer (score 0):

When moving to a newer version of Ubuntu, you have two options:

- To Upgrade.
- To do a fresh install.

Given that you moved from a very old version of Ubuntu, there is a high chance that an artifact from the old version has compromized your system somehow. This is common, and happens to the best of us. In my experience, as I have dealt with this sort of issue a lot, the quickest way to solve this issue is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop.

An analogy if you prefer, is that doing a fresh install is like tearing down a bug infested house, destroying all the nests and getting rid of all the water damage, and just building from scratch. All you do, is remove the furniture from your house to your neighbours garage, rebuild, and then move back in.